# HTML5 Video attribute support

Tags: html, video, attributes

I have a HTML5 video, working fine, and i'm happily smiling whenever i start my browser... However!

I know the Video tag isnt supported by some browsers, but i noticed there is a **difference in support for video attributes**/methods/whatever too. Is there a summary of this somewhere?

**For example:**
The poster attribute doesnt work in every browser, even if the vide DOES work!

I think its pretty worthless to just use an entire javascript library to take care of one attribute like poster, so **how to take care of this**?
Or am i completely wrong, and is IF video is supported, also every attribute supported the same way?

Please help me! :)

Thanks for all your advice,
WK

ps: I am using the video for everybody variant of the video. So thats working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this page a good resource (although it is starting to get old as it was earlier this year): http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5

On a separate note, I find if you go to mobile devices such as Android the browser support varies greatly per device. Even though they are "supported" I always get strange behavior.

As for poster, there is no good solution if you want to have support across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing your after?? [click me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).

Comment: No, im sorry :) I meant the specific use of attributes. Like poster, loop, etc. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is the following support for the HTML5 video tag:

1. Every modern browser that has support for `HTML 5` supports `<video>`
   meaning: IE9+, FF3.6+, Chrome, Opera, Safari
2. Internet Explorer 9 does not support the poster attribute. I believe
   there is even a bug about this on Microsoft connect.
3. Firefox does not support the loop attribute. (replaying a video after it has finished)
4. Different browsers support different video formats, IE9 supports
   H.264, Firefox supports ogg (Theora) and WebM etc, which means that you would need to provide all formats in order to be compatible with all browsers.

The rest is pretty much supported everywhere.

Comment: A partial answer, thanks! i was looking for some sort of overview. But you are completely right in saying that theyre all still implementing HTML5. So it will probably change a bit too.

Answer (score 1):

well, HTML 5 is not yet standardized. Due to this, every browser that support html5 works differently. As far video tag is concerned then you have to provide with different formats so as to get support on various browser list. You can test browser support on [this site](http://html5test.com/). Here you can get all the details about the extent your browser support to HTML5

Comment: Thanks, but not what i meant :) I was searching for a overview where i could see what attribute (like poster) was supported in what browser. And since i dont have every browser on my pc.... :) Thanks anyway!